# Xamarin.Forms - Popup Menu

Tags: popupmenu

Can any one help me write code for a ***Popupmenu*** using Xamarin.Forms? I also want to position the popups in certain areas of the screen like top left, top right, bottom right, and bottom left.

Comment: Hi Peter Schwartz .Have you found any solution for the same question?

Answer (score 3):

This webpage here should help you out quite a bit...

> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/pop-ups/

I believe you will want to go with something like this :

```
async void OnActionSheetSimpleClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Email", "Twitter", "Facebook");
    Debug.WriteLine ("Action: " + action);
}
```

This is simply how I interpreted your definition of popupmenu. If you are looking for just a simple alert there are other references on the webpage for that.

Comment: Thank you Peter for ur reply, but  i have to display context menu type. means can i changed the popmenu position like top left,top right,bottom corner etc..flexible to give the displayed popup postion

Comment: Just position the pop up in your xaml using some type of absolute positioning a good example is something like... AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5, .5, 50,50"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" where in this case your element will be placed in the middle of the screen (.5 , .5) and have width of 50 and height of 50. This will take care of your positioning issues then just bind the element to the command OnActionSheetSimpleClicked using commanding.

Comment: Thank u very much peter

Comment: Hi Peter Schwartz .Have you found any solution for the same question?